# Flattening multiple reactive arrays looses the reactivity (Array.flat())

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have been working on component which takes in a reactive Map<string, string[]> and combines all the values of this Map into single array. This resulting flattened array is put into a reactive object which is connected to the template. But once I flatten the reactive arrays, I loose the reactivity and the template is not updated on changing values of Map<string, string[]>

My component looks like

```
<template>
    <form :style="{ padding: '5px' }" @submit.prevent="submitResource">
        <template v-for="(v, k) in result">
            <div v-if="Array.isArray(v.value) && v.model"
                class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text res_name">{{ v.friendlyName ?? k }}</span>
                <select class="form-select shadow-none" v-model="v.model.value">
                    <option v-for="item in v.value" :key="(item as string)" :value="item">{{ item
                    }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </template>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">{{ actionText }}</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { TResourcesUI } from '@/types/TWebAppResources';
import { reactive, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
import { useAnalysisTypesStore } from '@/stores/report/analysistypes';

const props = defineProps<{ res: Resource, actionText: string }>()
const result: TResourcesUI = reactive({}) //reactive
const { AnalysisTypes } = useAnalysisTypesStore()
const UIfn = getCurrentInstance()!.appContext.config.globalProperties.$UIfn

prepResult()


function prepResult() {
    result['Type'] = { value: 'Parotta' }
    result['Types'] = { value: [...AnalysisTypes.values()].flat(), model: result.Type }
}

function submitResource() {
}

</script>
```

My state property is

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const useAnalysisTypesStore = defineStore("analysistypes", () => {
  const AnalysisTypes = reactive(new Map<string, string[]>());
  return {
    AllAnalysisTypes,
  };
});
```

I have a background process which updates the AnalysisTypes state. But the template isnt getting updated when I use `[...AnalysisTypes.values()].flat()`

But if I change the value to `result['Types'] = { value: [...AnalysisTypes.values()][0], model: result.Type }` I have the reactivity and template options are updated.

I have also tried computed property `const analysisTypes = computed(() => [...AnalysisTypes.values()].flat())`. This as well did not work.

What might be the reason for this ?

Comment: "I have a background process which updates the AnalysisTypes state" - this is not shown.  If you expect that result will react to AnalysisTypes changes then the expectation is wrong. "I have also tried computed property" - it's unknown how you used it. You probably need a watcher to keep result in sync with AnalysisTypes

Comment: I am updating the AnalysisTypes by this command AnalysisTypes.get(resDataType).push(...analysisTypes);   

I have used the computed property 'analysisTypes' as result['Types'] = { value: analysisTypes, model: result.Type } --> didnt work

But when I changed the value to just get the first element on the array, then it works
result['Types'] = { value: [...AnalysisTypes.values()][0], model: result.Type }

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive) for reactive, you should not be replacing the object you set with the reactive() method.

You should either flatten your data beforehand (when received), then just use that, keep the structure of the data as a Map or use ref instead. Changing the structure (flattening it) when you set it with the reactive() function kills its reactivity.

[As stated in their limitations of reactive section](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#limitations-of-reactive):

> when we destructure a reactive object's primitive type property into local variables, or when we pass that property into a function, we will lose the reactivity connection
>
> Due to these limitations, we recommend using ref() as the primary API for declaring reactive state.